# Connect WiFi on non-WiFi RPi

Tags: wifi, pi-zero, internet, esp8266

Yes, I know that I can't connect to Internet using simple RPi Zero (non-WiFi), but are there methods to connect it to WiFi using ESP8266 modules like on Arduinos?

Comment: use a WiFi Dongle?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to WiFi using [USB WiFi Dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY) and OTG Cable

Procedure is as simple, because pi0 has a mini USB, you will need a simple OTG Cable and a USB Dongle as given in the link there that will let you access the WiFi.

Comment: Whilst you may be correct, can you expand upon your answer, as it is rather short.

Comment: I really don't know what else to put up there to expand. Procedure is as simple, because pi0 has a mini USB, you will need a simple OTG Cable and a USB Dongle as given in the link there that will let you access the WiFi.

Comment: Fair enough. Please edit and add that information to your answer, and *not* in a comment. Thanks.